# Windows backup failure reading shadow copy on an unidentified volume

Tags: windows, windows-7, backup

I'm hitting this error running windows backup on a Windows 7 machine.

> *Windows Backup: Troubleshooting Options*
>
> Check your backup Windows Backup failed while trying to read from the shadow copy on one of the
> volumes being backed up. Please check in the event logs for any
> relevant errors.
>
> - Try to run backup again
> - Change backup settings Error code: `0x810000037`

So I'm assuming they're speaking of going into the `eventvwr` and scouting for certain logs, but what log types would I be hunting for to identify this troublesome volume? Is there's a known solution to identify the problem or a workaround to this backup error with code `0x810000037`?

[image: Windows backup troubleshooting options dialog]

(In the meantime I'll try trial and error removing several of the drives out of the backup to narrow down which one is presenting the problem.)

Comment: Why not use a more robust third-party tool that  performs a *full disk image* or a partial back-up, as does Windows? There are many free apps, such as Macrium Reflect and alternatives: https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/

Comment: posting some reference on the subject of shadow volume copying for the uninitiated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/volume-shadow-copy-service

Comment: Ah VSS -- that is the *one* Windows feature I would enjoy in Ubuntu, so images could be made with volume mounted. *sigh*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what happened was my `Volume Shadow Copy` service was *stopped* and configured for `Startup` with the `Manual` option selected. I was about to go down the rabbit hole for examining which of my several disks could have accounted for this behavior.

You can check the state of you OS by running `services.msc` and search for Volume Shadow Copy.

[image: services.msc]

Then note the condition its in and double click the row its in and you can then start and stop the service.
[image: Volume Shadow Copy Service]

The description for the service says it all right there...

> Description
>
> Manages and implements Volume Shadow Copies used for backup and other purposes. If this service is stopped, shadow copies will be unavailable for backup and the backup may fail. If this service is disabled, any services that explicitly depend on it will fail to start.

---

## Update 1

So this VSS service being stopped was only part of the story, I think somewhere along the line I configured this service to be manual, but even when starting it there is a certain disk on my system that is indeed yielding an error during the backup. I've been updating the backup configuration to select single drives at a time and carrying through the backup operation. So far I've eliminated 3 disks from my collection, the offending disk I have a strong suspicion for.

There are indeed a collection of logs in the `eventvwr` that I need to further analyze that surround the failure time. When the failure occurs the vss service is stopped and that put my system into a disabled state effectively since I was never able to run backups from that point forward (feels good to have some partial backups once again).